# Where to get ACCESS_TOKEN from?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The secrets.example.js file at the following location has ACCESS_TOKEN property. Where to get it from?

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/samples/browser/secrets.example.js

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to obtain an access token by first, [registering an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-app-registration), specifying the scopes you need and then, obtaining consent from a user or tenant admin. We recommend using an authentication library like [MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js).

If you're just prototyping, you can [grab an access token from Graph explorer](https://twitter.com/dansilver82/status/872520061843415040) to run the sample.

[Here is some additional information](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview) about auth tokens and Graph